# How to save a spark DataFrame as csv on disk?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For example, the result of this:

```
df.filter("project = 'en'").select("title","count").groupBy("title").sum()
```

would return an Array.

How to save a spark DataFrame as a csv file on disk ?

Comment: btw this doesn't return an array, but a DataFrame! [reference here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData)

Comment: If the answer given solves your question, please accept it and up-vote so we can class this question as resolved!

Answer (score 45):

Apache Spark does not support native CSV output on disk.

You have four available solutions though:

1. You can convert your Dataframe into an RDD :

   ```scala
   def convertToReadableString(r : Row) = ???
   df.rdd.map{ convertToReadableString }.saveAsTextFile(filepath)
   ```

   This will create a folder filepath. Under the file path, you'll find partitions files (e.g part-000*)

   What I usually do if I want to append all the partitions into a big CSV is

   ```
   cat filePath/part* > mycsvfile.csv
   ```

   Some will use **`coalesce(1,false)`** to create one partition from the RDD. It's usually a **bad practice**, since it may overwhelm the driver by pulling all the data you are collecting to it.

   Note that `df.rdd` will return an `RDD[Row]`.
2. With **Spark <2**, you can use databricks spark-csv [library](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv):

   - Spark 1.4+:

     ```scala
     df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(filepath)
     ```
   - Spark 1.3:

     ```scala
     df.save(filepath,"com.databricks.spark.csv")
     ```
3. With **Spark 2.x** the `spark-csv` package is not needed as it's included in Spark.

   ```
   df.write.format("csv").save(filepath)
   ```
4. You can convert to local Pandas data frame and use `to_csv` method (PySpark only).

**Note:** Solutions 1, 2 and 3 will result in CSV format files (`part-*`) generated by the underlying Hadoop API that Spark calls when you invoke `save`. You will have one `part-` file per partition.

Comment: I think that  `spark-csv` is preferred solution. It is not easy to create a correct csv line from scratch. All dialects and proper escaping can be quite tricky.

Comment: In PySpark you can also convert small table to Pandas and save locally. but it probably a Scala question.

Comment: If you feel like adding the information to the answer @zero323, please feel free to do so!

Comment: Guys do you know if it is possible to avoid the hadoopish format and store data to a file under a file name or `s3` key name of my choice instead of the directory with `_SUCCES` and `part-*` ?

Comment: I posted solution using spark-csv

Comment: Tried the 3rd point (for spark 2.x) to save csv on local machine with file:///path_to_file. But I am unable to locate the csv files anywhere. Have I missed anything?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53307036/spark-scala-cannot-find-the-file-written-as-csv-in-local-storage

Comment: @MihirMistry windows ?

Comment: @eliasah Yes on windows with spark 2.1.1 and scala 2.11
You can check the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53307036/spark-scala-cannot-find-the-file-written-as-csv-in-local-storage

Answer (score 28):

Writing dataframe to disk as csv is similar read from csv. If you want your result as one file, you can use coalesce.

```
df.coalesce(1)
      .write
      .option("header","true")
      .option("sep",",")
      .mode("overwrite")
      .csv("output/path")
```

If your result is an array  you should use language specific solution, not spark dataframe api. Because all these kind of results return driver machine.

Comment: this is WRONG!! and Dangerous! you should use .save() not .csv()!!!

Comment: You can either use format and save or directly use csv, parquet, etc. All same.

Comment: overwrite mode (with csv()) will delete all content of a folder if it exists

Comment: Of course, it will. This is just an example out of tens possibilities.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue where i had to save the contents of the dataframe to a csv file of name which i defined. `df.write("csv").save("<my-path>")` was creating directory than file. So have to come up with the following solutions. 
Most of the code is taken from the following [dataframe-to-csv](https://gist.github.com/dmpetrov/a4a5dc2cc8719619410e37dedde5130e) with little modifications to the logic.

```
def saveDfToCsv(df: DataFrame, tsvOutput: String, sep: String = ",", header: Boolean = false): Unit = {
    val tmpParquetDir = "Posts.tmp.parquet"

    df.repartition(1).write.
        format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
        option("header", header.toString).
        option("delimiter", sep).
        save(tmpParquetDir)

    val dir = new File(tmpParquetDir)
    val newFileRgex = tmpParquetDir + File.separatorChar + ".part-00000.*.csv"
    val tmpTsfFile = dir.listFiles.filter(_.toPath.toString.matches(newFileRgex))(0).toString
    (new File(tmpTsvFile)).renameTo(new File(tsvOutput))

    dir.listFiles.foreach( f => f.delete )
    dir.delete
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. I needed to write down csv file on driver while I was connect to cluster in client mode.

I wanted to reuse the same CSV parsing code as Apache Spark to avoid potential errors.

I checked spark-csv code and found code responsible for converting dataframe into raw csv `RDD[String]` in `com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvSchemaRDD`.

Sadly it is hardcoded with `sc.textFile` and the end of relevant method.

I copy-pasted that code and removed last lines with `sc.textFile` and returned RDD directly instead.

My code:

```
/*
  This is copypasta from com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvSchemaRDD
  Spark's code has perfect method converting Dataframe -> raw csv RDD[String]
  But in last lines of that method it's hardcoded against writing as text file -
  for our case we need RDD.
 */
object DataframeToRawCsvRDD {

  val defaultCsvFormat = com.databricks.spark.csv.defaultCsvFormat

  def apply(dataFrame: DataFrame, parameters: Map[String, String] = Map())
           (implicit ctx: ExecutionContext): RDD[String] = {
    val delimiter = parameters.getOrElse("delimiter", ",")
    val delimiterChar = if (delimiter.length == 1) {
      delimiter.charAt(0)
    } else {
      throw new Exception("Delimiter cannot be more than one character.")
    }

    val escape = parameters.getOrElse("escape", null)
    val escapeChar: Character = if (escape == null) {
      null
    } else if (escape.length == 1) {
      escape.charAt(0)
    } else {
      throw new Exception("Escape character cannot be more than one character.")
    }

    val quote = parameters.getOrElse("quote", "\"")
    val quoteChar: Character = if (quote == null) {
      null
    } else if (quote.length == 1) {
      quote.charAt(0)
    } else {
      throw new Exception("Quotation cannot be more than one character.")
    }

    val quoteModeString = parameters.getOrElse("quoteMode", "MINIMAL")
    val quoteMode: QuoteMode = if (quoteModeString == null) {
      null
    } else {
      QuoteMode.valueOf(quoteModeString.toUpperCase)
    }

    val nullValue = parameters.getOrElse("nullValue", "null")

    val csvFormat = defaultCsvFormat
      .withDelimiter(delimiterChar)
      .withQuote(quoteChar)
      .withEscape(escapeChar)
      .withQuoteMode(quoteMode)
      .withSkipHeaderRecord(false)
      .withNullString(nullValue)

    val generateHeader = parameters.getOrElse("header", "false").toBoolean
    val headerRdd = if (generateHeader) {
      ctx.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
        csvFormat.format(dataFrame.columns.map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]): _*)
      ))
    } else {
      ctx.sparkContext.emptyRDD[String]
    }

    val rowsRdd = dataFrame.rdd.map(row => {
      csvFormat.format(row.toSeq.map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]): _*)
    })

    headerRdd union rowsRdd
  }

}
```